# Matlab fmincon increasing function value

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm using Matlab's fmincon function for optimization, but experience the function value increases instead of decreases, even though all of my constraint functions at all iterates are satisfied.

My optimization problem consist of a (smooth and continuous) cost function with two design variables to be minimized and six (smooth and continuous) constraint functions. The cost function, design variables and constraint functions are all normalized, hence the initial cost function value is 1, the initial variables 1 with bounds [0.5 1.5] and the constraint functions are initially in the range -1 to 0 (constraints must be below 0). Both cost and constraint functions are non-linear and I use finite (forward) difference for the gradients. The constraint functions are very costly to calculate (4-5 min.) as a commercial FE program is part of the function.

fmincon options are given as

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','OutputFcn',@outfun,... 
    'Display','iter-detailed','Maxiter',maxIter,...
    'TolX',1e-6,'TolCon',1e-3,'TolFun',1e-6,'DiffMinChange',1e-3);
```

An an example of the iteration sequence is shown below

```
                                        First-order      Norm of
Iter F-count         f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
0       3    1.000000e+00    0.000e+00    1.443e-01
1       7    1.014622e+00    0.000e+00    9.874e-02    5.697e-02
2      10    1.023593e+00    0.000e+00    1.378e-01    6.169e-02
3      14    1.047664e+00    0.000e+00    4.083e-01    1.260e-01
4      18    1.116892e+00    0.000e+00    1.967e-01    2.358e-01
5      21    1.131103e+00    0.000e+00    2.020e-01    5.315e-02
6      28    1.130283e+00    0.000e+00    1.757e-01    1.141e-02
7      36    1.127147e+00    0.000e+00    2.650e-01    1.812e-02
8      45    1.114609e+00    0.000e+00    1.074e-01    4.428e-02
9      49    1.106101e+00    0.000e+00    6.890e-01    4.329e-02
```

and the iteration sequence plotted:
[image: Iteration sequence]

I tried using the sqp algorithm, but the result is the same. I would very much appreciate any explanation for this behavior and any suggestions on how to make the algorithm decrease the cost function.

Thank you in advance.
Mads Baandrup

Comment: Can you also show the iteration output of the SQP algorithm?